# Object animator not removing update listener android

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

Good day.I have an scenario where this half normal object animator keeps firing over and over causing heap grow and ofcourse out of memory issue at some point.Here is how it go. I have made static method for rainbow animation like this.

```
  public static ObjectAnimator startRainbowAnimation(Context context,
                                                   String textToShow,
                                                   final TextView textViewToAttach) {
    AnimatedColorSpan span = new AnimatedColorSpan(context);
    final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(textToShow);
    String substring = textToShow;
    int start = textToShow.indexOf(substring);
    int end = start + substring.length();
    spannableString.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);

    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            span, ANIMATED_COLOR_SPAN_FLOAT_PROPERTY, 0, 100);
    objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new FloatEvaluator());
    objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            System.gc();
            Log.d("Fafasfasfas", "onAnimationUpdate: inside true");
            textViewToAttach.setText(spannableString);
        }
    });
    objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    objectAnimator.setDuration(DURATION);
    objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    objectAnimator.start();
    return objectAnimator;
}

private static final Property<AnimatedColorSpan, Float> ANIMATED_COLOR_SPAN_FLOAT_PROPERTY
        = new Property<AnimatedColorSpan, Float>(Float.class, "ANIMATED_COLOR_SPAN_FLOAT_PROPERTY") {
    @Override
    public void set(AnimatedColorSpan span, Float value) {
        span.setTranslateXPercentage(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Float get(AnimatedColorSpan span) {
        return span.getTranslateXPercentage();
    }
};
```

I am calling this method like this inside an recycler view adapter

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ChatModel chatModel = chatModelList.get(position);

        System.gc();

        String messageBody = chatModel.getMessage().replaceAll("userid=" + chatModel.getUserId() + ":" + Constants.TYPE_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT, "").replaceAll("userid=" + chatModel.getOpponentId() + ":" + Constants.TYPE_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT, "");
        holder.message.setText(messageBody);
         if (showAsRainbow) {
                if (holder.message.getTag() == null) {
                    objectAnimator = RainbowAnimation.startRainbowAnimation(mContext, messageBody, holder.message);
                    holder.message.setTag(ANIMATED);
                }
            } else {
                objectAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
                objectAnimator.removeAllListeners();
                objectAnimator.end();
                objectAnimator.cancel();
                holder.message.setTag(null);
            }

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.chatViewBubble.getLayoutParams();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams deliveryStatusParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.deliveryStatus.getLayoutParams();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams gifChatViewLayoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.imageViewWrapper.getLayoutParams();

        checkForGif(chatModel, holder);

        if (mCurrentUserId.equals(chatModel.getUserId())) {
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = Dp.toDps(mContext, 16);
            deliveryStatusParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            gifChatViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

            holder.chatViewBubble.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(gifChatViewLayoutParams);

            holder.chatViewBubble.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.outgoing_message_bg));
            if (chatModel.getDeliveryStatus().equals(Constants.STATUS_DELIVERED)) {
                if (position >= chatModelList.size() - 1) {
                    holder.deliveryStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    holder.deliveryStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                holder.deliveryStatus.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.sentText));
            } else if (chatModel.getDeliveryStatus().equals(Constants.STATUS_NOT_DELIVERED)) {
                holder.deliveryStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (updating) {
                    holder.deliveryStatus.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.sendingNowText) + percentage + " %");
                } else {
                    holder.deliveryStatus.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.sendingNowText));
                }

            }
        } else {
            holder.chatViewBubble.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.incoming_message_bg));
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            gifChatViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

            holder.chatViewBubble.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(gifChatViewLayoutParams);
            holder.deliveryStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }
```

Thi issue is that if you noticed the `Log.d()` keeps firing even after the cancle and end was called on the objectAnimator and yes i have checked that cancel and end is being called.So i have no clue what i have done wrong.Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I see lot's of guys been looking at the post,meaning they got this issue too so i got the solution somehow fixed...Issue is that this damned ObjectAnimator when done inside an loop even with static method,each time is being created new reference to it.So you have to do something like this.Have an array list of object animators,on each call add items to array list.Whenever you want to stop it just simply loop through array and stop all object animators.Here is the code

```
private ArrayList<ObjectAnimator> objectAnimators = new ArrayList<>();
  public void startRainbowAnimation(Context context,
                                  final String textToShow,
                                  final TextView textViewToAttach) {
    stopCalled = false;
    AnimatedColorSpan span = new AnimatedColorSpan(context);
    final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(textToShow);
    String substring = textToShow;
    int start = textToShow.indexOf(substring);
    int end = start + substring.length();
    spannableString.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);

    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            span, animatedColorSpanFloatProperty, 0, 100);
    objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new FloatEvaluator());

    objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            System.gc();
            if (!stopCalled) {
                textViewToAttach.setText(spannableString);
            }
        }
    });
    objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    objectAnimator.setDuration(DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 3);
    objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    objectAnimator.start();
    objectAnimators.add(objectAnimator);
}
objectAnimators here is an array list of object animators like this
```

And here is how you stop all of them to get ride of infinite update listener call firing.

```
 public void stopRainbowAnimation() {
    System.gc();
    stopCalled = true;
    if (!objectAnimators.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectAnimators.size(); i++) {
            ObjectAnimator eachAnimator = objectAnimators.get(i);
            eachAnimator.setRepeatCount(0);
            eachAnimator.end();
            eachAnimator.cancel();
            eachAnimator.removeAllListeners();
            eachAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
        }
        objectAnimators.clear();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone

Comment: ObjectAnimator eachAnimator = objectAnimators.get(i);
            eachAnimator.setRepeatCount(0);
            eachAnimator.end();
            eachAnimator.cancel();
            eachAnimator.removeAllListeners();
            eachAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners();

works fine for my issue.

Comment: Correct answer by Jean.. Thank you :)